# Attept to access wsl via jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am writing bash commands in a jupyter notebook, installed via Anaconda on a Windows 10 machine and I want to use it to run and collect results from Python programs on wsl, but currently, I can't even get it to print a working directory.

!wsl cd /mnt/d && pwd

bizarrely gives the error

'pwd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

why?
and can you help me to get pwd via wsl commands to work?

Comment: Can you try `!wsl cd /mnt/d -e pwd`